# How can I use django-filter's DateTimeFromToRangeFilter with Graphene?

Tags: python, django, graphql, django-filter, graphene-django

I'm attempting to use an instance of django-filter's DateTimeFromToRangeFilter in conjunction with a custom `FilterSet`. However, this does not work when I attempt to do the following:

```
class CustomFilterSet(FilterSet):
    modified = django_filters.IsoDateTimeFromToRangeFilter()

    class Meta:
        fields = "__all__"
        model = Custom
```

This does not result in additional fields or annotations being created, like I'd expect based on [the docs](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html?highlight=datetime#isodatetimefromtorangefilter). Something like:

```
f = F({'modified_after': '...', 'modified_before': '...'})
```

If I inspect the single field (`modified`) which has been added to my DjangoFilterConnectionField, I see the following:

```
{'creation_counter': 395, 'name': None, '_type': <String meta=<ScalarOptions name='String'>>, 'default_value': Undefined, 'description': None, 'deprecation_reason': None}
```

So, how do I configure this filter such that I can write a query like the following?

```
query {
    allTheSmallThings(
        modified_before: "2023-09-26 17:21:22.921692+00:00"
    ) {
        edges {
            node {
                id
            }
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I can confirm that I'm able to use the FilterSet subclass as documented. The issue seems to be with the fields that are/not being generated by Graphene.

Comment: [The bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77182230/timeline) attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To filter a DateTime field using a custom FilterSet in Graphene-Django, you can follow these steps:

> 1. Define a custom DateTime filter field using IsoDateTimeFromToRangeFilter from django-filter in your custom
>    FilterSet class.
> 2. Make sure that the filter field name you define matches the name you will use in your GraphQL query.
> 3. Ensure that your GraphQL schema includes the custom FilterSet and
>    field names correctly.

Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

Assuming you have a model named **Custom**, here's how you can define a custom FilterSet and integrate it into your GraphQL schema:

```
import django_filters
import graphene
from graphene import relay
from graphene_django.filter import DjangoFilterConnectionField
from graphene_django.types import DjangoObjectType

from .models import Custom  # Import your Custom model here

class CustomFilterSet(django_filters.FilterSet):
    modified_before = django_filters.IsoDateTimeFilter(
        field_name='modified', lookup_expr='lte'
    )
    modified_after = django_filters.IsoDateTimeFilter(
        field_name='modified', lookup_expr='gte'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Custom
        fields = []

class CustomNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Custom
        interfaces = (relay.Node,)

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    all_the_small_things = DjangoFilterConnectionField(
        CustomNode, filterset_class=CustomFilterSet
    )

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
```

With this setup, you can use the **modified_before** and **modified_after** filters in your GraphQL query like this:

```
query {
    allTheSmallThings(
        modified_before: "2023-09-26T17:21:22.921692Z"
    ) {
        edges {
            node {
                id
                # Add other fields you want to retrieve
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure to adjust the **field_name** and **lookup_expr** values in the **CustomFilterSet** to match your model's field name and the filter conditions you want to apply.

Additionally, ensure that you have imported the necessary modules and set up your GraphQL schema correctly.

Comment: Thanks. This is more or less what I wound up doing. I was figuring there'd be a more succinct way to achieve it, though.

Comment: Yeah. Agreed. I hope this is by far the efficient way though.